# the program does not terminate

Tags: c, arrays, string, while-loop

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


int main(){

    int num_test,i,j,k;
    scanf("%d ",&num_test);
    char array[num_test][35];
    for (i=0;i<num_test;i++){
        fgets(array[i],35,stdin);
        array[i][strcspn(array[i],"\n")]='\0';
    }
    for (j=0;j<num_test;j++){
        for (k=0;k<35;k++){
            while(array[j][k] != '\0'){        // I am seeing when the name entered ends then this loop should stop. 
                if (array[j][1] == 'a'){
                    array[j][1] = 'A';
                }
            }
        }           
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The above code does not terminate but keeps on taking inputs and shows no result. The problem does not persist if I remove the second for loop. I am inputting 2 to scanf and then james and then bond to the two fgets but it just keeps on asking for more inputs.

Comment: `while(array[j][k] != '\0')` ==> `if(array[j][k] == '\0') {break;}` because you are already looping `k`. The following lines should use index `k` not `1`, assuming you want to uppercase every `'a'`.

Comment: Why are you expecting any results? Your code doesn't output anything.

Comment: @ChrisTurner the programme does not terminate, it keeps on taking inputs

Comment: No - it only takes in `num_test` lines of input. It doesn't terminate because of the unnecessary `while` loop as per @WeatherVane's comment

Comment: Indeed the `while` loop will never terminate, once begun because its body changes nothing that will cause it to terminate.

Comment: tx @WeatherVane it was a stupid one sorry for that

Comment: This is a good time to learn how to use a debugger - you can step through your code line by line and see what it is doing

Comment: This is also a good time to learn how to give meaningful names to variables. 'array', 'i,j,k' and the like are unhelpful:(

Answer (score 0):

In this code block

```
for (j=0;j<num_test;j++){
    for (k=0;k<35;k++){
        while(array[j][k] != '\0'){
            if (array[j][1] == 'a'){
                array[j][1] = 'A';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You have an unnecessary `while` loop which will never terminate, once begun, because nothing within that loop will change the result of loop condition. Assuming your aim is to change every occurrence of `'a'` to `'A'` I suggest

```
for(j = 0; j < num_test; j++) {
    for(k = 0; k < 35; k++) {
        if(array[j][k] == '\0') {
            break;                      // quit when terminator found
        }
        if(array[j][k] == 'a') {        // changed 1 to k
            array[j][k] = 'A';          // changed 1 to k
        }
    }
}
```

I would also suggest replacing the "magic number" `35` with a `#define` or `const int`.